# Selection Errors

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

How can I get my selection box to show an error if nothing is selected? Currently, it doesn't give me any errors upon submitting because the "select" field is the first item in the field box so it's implying that it's filled in.

This is only for gender country and state.

```
include 'connection.php';    
if ($_POST['submit']=="Sign Up") {  
    if (!$_POST['firstname']) $error.="<br />Please enter your first name";
        else {          
            if (!preg_match("/^[- '\p{L}]+$/u", $_POST['firstname'])) $error.="<br />First name may only contain letters";          
        }
    if (!$_POST['lastname']) $error.="<br />Please enter your last name";
        else {          
            if (!preg_match("/^[- '\p{L}]+$/u", $_POST['lastname'])) $error.="<br />Last name may only contain letters";            
        }
    if (!$_POST['email']) $error.="<br />Please enter your email";
        else if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) $error.="<br />Please enter a valid email address";           
    if (!$_POST['password']) $error.="<br />Please enter your password";
        else {          
            if (strlen($_POST['password'])<8) $error.="<br />Please enter a password with at least 8 characters";
            if (!preg_match('`[A-Z]`', $_POST['password'])) $error.="<br />Please enter at least 1 capital letter";         
        }
    if ($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['confirmpassword']) 
        $error.="<br />Your passwords do not match.";
    if (!$_POST['gender']) $error.="<br />Please enter your gender";
    if (!$_POST['country']) $error.="<br />Please enter your country";
    if (!$_POST['s
```

tate']) $error.="
Please enter your state";

Form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-5 control-label">First Name*</label>  
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="form-control input-md" value="<?php echo addslashes ($_POST['firstname']); ?>" />   
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Last Name*</label>  
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control input-md" value="<?php echo addslashes ($_POST['lastname']); ?>" />  
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Email*</label>  
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control input-md" value="<?php echo addslashes ($_POST['email']); ?>" />
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Password*</label>  
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control input-md" />   
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Confirm Password*</label>  
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" class="form-control input-md" />   
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Gender*</label>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <select id="gender" name="gender" class="form-control">
                    <option>Select</option>
                    <option>Male</option>
                    <option>Female</option>
                </select>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Country*</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <select id="country" name ="country" class="form-control"></select>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-5 control-label">State*</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">      
                <select name ="state" id ="state" class="form-control"></select>
                    <script language="javascript">
                    populateCountries("country", "state");
                    </script>
            </div>
    </div>

        <div class="text-center">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-kani btn-lg" value="Sign Up"/>                   
        </div>


</form>
```

JS File

```
// Countries
var country_arr = new Array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antartica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Ashmore and Cartier Island", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina",  Georgia and South Sandwich Islands", "Spain", "Spratly Islands", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Tobago", "Toga", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Trinidad", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Tuvalu", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "Uruguay", "USA", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Virgin Islands", "Wales", "Wallis and Futuna", "West Bank", "Western Sahara", "Yemen", "Yugoslavia", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe");

// States
var s_a = new Array();
s_a[0]="";
s_a[1]="Badakhshan|Badghis|Baghlan|Balkh|Bamian|Farah|Faryab|Ghazni|Ghowr|Helmand|Herat|Jowzjan|Kabol|Kandahar|Kapisa|Konar|Kondoz|Laghman|Lowgar|Nangarhar|Nimruz|Oruzgan|Paktia|Paktika|Parvan|Samangan|Sar-e Pol|Takhar|Vardak|Zabol";
s_a[2]="Berat|Bulqize|Delvine|Devoll (Bilisht)|Diber (Peshkopi)|Durres|Elbasan|Fier|Gjirokaster|Gramsh|Has (Krume)|Kavaje|Kolonje (Erseke)|Korce|Kruje|Kucove|Kukes|Kurbin|Lezhe|Librazhd|Lushnje|Malesi e Madhe (Koplik)|Mallakaster (Ballsh)|Mat (Burrel)|Mirdite (Rreshen)|Peqin|Permet|Pogradec|Puke|Sarande|Shkoder|Skrapar (Corovode)|Tepelene|Tirane (Tirana)|Tirane (Tirana)|Tropoje (Bajram Curri)|Vlore";
s_a[3]="Adrar|Ain Defla|Ain Temouchent|Alger|Annaba|Batna|Bechar|Bejaia|Biskra|Blida|Bordj Bou Arreridj|Bouira|Boumerdes|Chlef|Constantine|Djelfa|El Bayadh|El Oued|El Tarf|Ghardaia|Guelma|Illizi|Jijel|Khenchela|Laghouat|M'Sila|Mascara|Medea|Mila|Mostaganem|Naama|Oran|Ouargla|Oum el Bouaghi|Relizane|Saida|Setif|Sidi Bel Abbes|Skikda|Souk Ahras|Tamanghasset|Tebessa|Tiaret|Tindouf|Tipaza|Tissemsilt|Tizi Ouzou|Tlemcen";
s_a[4]="Eastern|Manu'a|Rose Island|Swains Island|Western";
s_a[5]="Andorra la Vella|Bengo|Benguela|Bie|Cabinda|Canillo|Cuando Cubango|Cuanza Norte|Cuanza Sul|Cunene|Encamp|Escaldes-Engordany|Huambo|Huila|La Massana|Luanda|Lunda Norte|Lunda Sul|Malanje|Moxico|Namibe|Ordino|Sant Julia de Loria|Uige|Zaire";
s_a[6]="Anguilla";
s_a[7]="Antartica";
s_a[8]="Barbuda|Redonda|Saint George|Saint John|Saint Mary|Saint Paul|Saint Peter|Saint Philip";
s_a[9]="Antartica e Islas del Atlantico Sur|Buenos Aires|Buenos Aires Capital Federal|Catamarca|Chaco|Chubut|Cordoba|Corrientes|Entre Rios|Formosa|Jujuy|La Pampa|La Rioja|Mendoza|Misiones|Neuquen|Rio Negro|Salta|San Juan|San Luis|Santa Cruz|Santa Fe|Santiago del Estero|Tierra del Fuego|Tucuman";
s_a[10]="Aragatsotn|Ararat|Armavir|Geghark'unik'|Kotayk'|Lorri|Shirak|Syunik'|Tavush|Vayots' Dzor|Yerevan";
s_a[11]="Aruba";
s_a[12]="Ashmore and Cartier Island";
s_a[13]="Australian Capital Territory|New South Wales|Northern Territory|Queensland|South Australia|Tasmania|Victoria|Western Australia";

s_a[247]="West Bank";
s_a[248]="Western Sahara";
s_a[249]="'Adan|'Ataq|Abyan|Al Bayda'|Al Hudaydah|Al Jawf|Al Mahrah|Al Mahwit|Dhamar|Hadhramawt|Hajjah|Ibb|Lahij|Ma'rib|Sa'dah|San'a'|Ta'izz";
s_a[250]="Kosovo|Montenegro|Serbia|Vojvodina";
s_a[251]="Central|Copperbelt|Eastern|Luapula|Lusaka|North-Western|Northern|Southern|Western";
s_a[252]="Bulawayo|Harare|ManicalandMashonaland Central|Mashonaland East|Mashonaland West|Masvingo|Matabeleland North|Matabeleland South|Midlands";


function populateStates( countryElementId, stateElementId ){

    var selectedCountryIndex = document.getElementById( countryElementId ).selectedIndex;

    var stateElement = document.getElementById( stateElementId );

    stateElement.length=0;  // Fixed by Julian Woods
    stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Select State','');
    stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;

    var state_arr = s_a[selectedCountryIndex].split("|");

    for (var i=0; i<state_arr.length; i++) {
        stateElement.options[stateElement.length] = new Option(state_arr[i],state_arr[i]);
    }
}

function populateCountries(countryElementId, stateElementId){
    // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
    var countryElement = document.getElementById(countryElementId);
    countryElement.length=0;
    countryElement.options[0] = new Option('Select Country','-1');
    countryElement.selectedIndex = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<country_arr.length; i++) {
        countryElement.options[countryElement.length] = new Option(country_arr[i],country_arr[i]);
    }

    // Assigned all countries. Now assign event listener for the states.

    if( stateElementId ){
        countryElement.onchange = function(){
            populateStates( countryElementId, stateElementId );
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: *"How can I get my selection box to show an error if nothing is selected?"* - What selection box? I see `if (!$_POST['gender'])` use `if(!isset(...` and/or `if(empty(...`

Comment: If I was to paste the whole form it'll be too much to read! Anyway,  every other field gets an error when left blank, just looking how to get away from the select dropdown fields as it is letting me get away with "SELECT"

Comment: Re-read my comment. Use `isset()` and/or `empty()` instead of `!$_POST` that isn't 100% reliable.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work. Still letting me pass because of the default "select" value in the form field

Comment: You should use consistent bracing throughout your code. Plus, your code in your question `if (!$_POST['s

tate']) $error.="` is broken, if that's your actual code. Is your select "named"? It's really hard to tell without a sample of your form. I can comment till midnight and still won't resolve it.

Comment: If your select's default value is `value="Make a selection"`, then do `if($_POST['select_name'] == "Make a selection"){ // do something }` that's the best I can offer without knowing what your form looks like, sorry. Consult Rasclatt's answer below.

Comment: `<option>Male</option>` and the other option should have values for them, that's why. Do `<option value="Male">Male</option>` and do the same for the other(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should look like:

```
<select id="gender" name="gender" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

The evaluation line will be:

```
if((isset($_POST['gender']) && empty($_POST['gender'])) || (!isset($_POST['gender']))) $error.="<br />Please enter your gender";
```

Your select defaults will be empty then. You will be able check for empty at that point.

As a side note, to skip all this php validation, using jQuery validation will save on 95% of your php on this.

Comment: How would that if(isset) code look like though with the suggestion you made? Modyfying the form to how you say is not a problem, just need to know the code to show the error once I convert that over.

Comment: You could say `if(isset($_POST['gender']) && !empty($_POST['gender'])) { code here }`

Comment: The important part is that your form selects have option values that are empty as the select default.

Comment: So I made the select value="" , male value=male, and female value=female......and changed the code to     if(isset($_POST['gender']) && !empty($_POST['gender'])) $error.="<br />Please select your gender";   and it is now showing me an error no matter what is selected, default select, male or female.

Comment: I was checking for not empty. You want to check for empty. Check my revision in my answer.

Comment: I figured out with both your help, unfortunately, i can only vote one. They should change this site a bit to accomadate all answers that throw in a little suggestion each that comes out with a good outcome.

Comment: @Anthony Glad you found your solution. Now you see why it's important to show us your form or part of it (the affected portion) ;)